# Ignoring NULL values within an aggregate operation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following MongoDB aggregate operation which is working fine but it also seems to be returning NULL values.

How can I ignore NULL values against projectIP field?

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
    [
     { $match:   {projectIP: { $exists:true }}},
     { $project: {projectIP: "$projectIP",_id : 0}},
     { $group:   {_id: "$projectIP"}},
     { $sort:    {projectIP: 1}}
    ];
)
```

Comment: `{ $match: { projectIP: { $exists:true }}}`

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet unfortunately didn't seem to work. Added this after the `$sort{}`

Comment: Not after the `$sort`. This should be the top of the pipeline above `$project`

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet Added to the top as shown in updated question and sorry, still showing my NULL value in my select drop-down list.

Comment: Seems some of the keys contain `null` values. Add this as well `{ $match: { projectIP: { $exists:true, $ne: null }}}` by replacing the first stage in your query

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet - your solution solved my problem. Are you able to add it as an answer to my thread and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems some of the keys contain `null` values. Add this as well

```
{ $match: { projectIP: { $exists:true, $ne: null }}}
```

by replacing the first stage in your query

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a value (0 or anything) to them instead of a null value.

Here how you do it

```
projectIP: { $ifNull: [ "$projectIP", 0.0 ] }
```

Comment: Will this actually ignore the NULL value as I am displaying the values in a select drop-down list where I don't want to show any NULLs.

Comment: It will not ignore null values but will assign null fields a value. Useful if your code throws an exception with null values.

Comment: Thanks for the info but in this scenario, I need the null values ignored altogether.